# Can I start a home based business with an online company, if I owe back taxes?

Tags: united-states, taxes, self-employment

I am currently looking at an online company that was advertised as a way to make extra money from home on the internet. It has a decent start up and the information provided on the website about the business and the contact consultant seem to be legit. I am currently in an installment agreement with the IRS and my wages from my full time job are being garnished by the state.  Am I eligible to start up a home base business while I owe these taxes.

Comment: Note that almost all such 'opportunities' are scams. In order to provide a complete answer, you'll need to explain the terms of your installment agreement with the IRS. Also, just curious. If you have the money to start up a business, why aren't you using it to pay back the money you owe?

Comment: The start up of the business is just 24.95 per month and the annual fee is waived this month. My installment agreement is monthly and the payment is drafted from my account. I am paying back the money I owe with the installment agreement.

Comment: @user11404 $24.95 for what? Don't you think its a scam?

Comment: I strongly recommend you read through a few links on work-at-home scams, e.g. [fraud.org](http://www.fraud.org/scams/general-fraud/work-at-home-scams), [forbes](http://www.forbes.com/sites/groupthink/2011/12/13/16-work-at-home-scams-to-avoid/), [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work-at-home_scheme), and the [FTC](http://www.consumer.ftc.gov/articles/0175-work-home-businesses) ([cached version](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:6HBgSXGPEu0J:www.consumer.ftc.gov/articles/0175-work-home-businesses+&cd=5&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us)) before joining something like this, to be safe

Answer (score 2):

You're eligible to do whatever you please, regardless of what you *owe* as long as you're in a payment plan approved by the IRS which you follow religiously.

That said, let me incorporate some of the comments, as they're important:

ChrisInEdmonton said:

> Note that almost all such 'opportunities' are scams. In order to
>   provide a complete answer, you'll need to explain the terms of your
>   installment agreement with the IRS. Also, just curious. If you have
>   the money to start up a business, why aren't you using it to pay back
>   the money you owe

John Bensin added:

> I strongly recommend you read through a few links on work-at-home
>   scams, e.g. [fraud.org](http://www.fraud.org/scams/general-fraud/work-at-home-scams), [forbes](http://www.forbes.com/sites/groupthink/2011/12/13/16-work-at-home-scams-to-avoid/), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work-at-home_scheme), and the [FTC](http://www.consumer.ftc.gov/articles/0175-work-home-businesses)
>   before joining something like this, to be safe